# Centeroids for countries in cartopy

Tags: shapely, cartopy, centroid

I would like to use somehow meaningful centers for labels etc. Here is my code so far:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io import shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

geo_axes = plt.axes((2, 2, 2, 2), projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0.0, globe=None))
geo_axes.set_global()

file = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='10m', category='cultural', name='admin_0_countries')
all_countries = list(shpreader.Reader(file).records())

country_centroids = {country.attributes['SU_A3']: (country.geometry.centroid.y, country.geometry.centroid.x) for country in all_countries if country.attributes['SU_A3']}
for label in {'DEU', 'FRA', 'USA'}:
    geo_axes.plot(country_centroids[label][1], country_centroids[label][0], marker='x', color='red')

geo_axes.add_geometries([country.geometry for country in countries if country.attributes['SU_A3'] in {'DEU', 'FRA', 'USA'}], ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='black', zorder=0)
geo_axes.add_geometries([country.geometry for country in countries if country.attributes['SU_A3'] not in {'DEU', 'FRA', 'USA'}], ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='0.9', edgecolor='black', zorder=0)
```

[image]

For Germany, e.g., this is straight forward (no oversea regions, etc.) and it works. However, for USA, for example, it's already bad and, for example, for France it is very misleading (i.e. France's center is in Spain).

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "meaningful centers"? I think I know what you mean, but I just want to make sure. In the case of the USA, do you want your centroid to be generated according to the **Continental** USA? And in France, you just want the centroid to be generated within the land-mass portion of France that's within continental Europe?

Comment: If what I described in the comment above is what you are looking for, you likely will have to find a geographic file that ONLY includes the *main* land-masses of each country, or at least find some kind of rule to identify those main landmasses within the `country` objects.